# Как исправить ошибку “Cannot read property 'call' of undefined. Exception occurred when checking element , check the 'rules' method”?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation

Имеется следующий код для валидации формы

```
$('form').validate({
     errorElement: "div",

     errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         $('.error-messages').append(error);
     },

     submitHandler: function() {
         console.log("Таблица успешно обновлена!")
     }
});

$('.validating').rules('add', {
    rules: {
        number: true
    },
    messages: {
        number: "Введите цифры"
    },
});
```

При попытке запустить код в консоли появляется ошибка “Cannot read property 'call' of undefined. Exception occurred when checking element , check the 'rules' method”. Как исправить указанную ошибку?
Код находится здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/d2pge08f/1/

Comment: откуда взят пример данного кода? Имеется ввиду примеры вызовов validate и rules

Comment: Написал, основываясь на доках: https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/
В документации говорится, что validate() вызывается первым

Comment: неверный объект передаешь в качестве параметра

Comment: плюс обрати внимание, что это `add` добавляет rule только для первого элемента

Comment: @Grundy, да, все так. Попробовал пойти другим путем: https://jsfiddle.net/waLgfv6m/
Но не сработало тоже

Comment: Потому что ты передаешь **НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ** объект

Comment: Перечитал доку, понял ошибку, пофиксил. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве параметра был передан неверный объект, объект должен был выглядеть следующим образом:

```
{
    number: true,
    messages: {
        number: "Введите цифры"
    },
}
```